# How to solve the error: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'users' is a get-only property" in xcode12 & swiftui

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

I'm getting the above error when I try to append to one of my arrays in my profile model.

Here is my profile model code:

```
import Foundation

struct UserProfile: Codable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: Int16
    var password: String
    var email: String
    
    
}

extension UserProfile {
    static var users: [UserProfile] {
        [
        UserProfile(firstName: "aryan", lastName: "chordia", age: 21, password: "123", email: "aryanchordia@gmail.com"),
        UserProfile(firstName: "tyler", lastName: "duic", age: 21, password: "123", email: "tduic@andrew.cmu.edu"),
        ]
    }
}

extension UserProfile {
    struct Data {
        var firstName: String = ""
        var lastName: String = ""
        var age: Int16 = 21
        var password: String = ""
        var email: String = ""
    }
    
    var data: Data {
        return Data(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age, password: password, email: email)
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to append to my UserProfile.users array in SignUpView.swift

```
func signup() -> Bool {
        let user = UserProfile(firstName: userData.firstName, lastName: userData.lastName, age: 21, password: userData.password, email: userData.email)
        UserProfile.users.append(user)
        return true
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using computed property here. Hence, the value is computed and you can not set it.

You can create your array with a function like that or declare is immediately with the correct value:

```
static var users: [UserProfile] = {
    [
    UserProfile(firstName: "aryan", lastName: "chordia", age: 21, password: "123", email: "aryanchordia@gmail.com"),
    UserProfile(firstName: "tyler", lastName: "duic", age: 21, password: "123", email: "tduic@andrew.cmu.edu"),
    ]
}()
```

Comment: Ok just tried this but im getting the error "expected declaration"

Comment: @AryanChordia You might have pasted the code at the wrong position not inside a class or function .. check that.

Comment: Not sure exactly what u mean. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @davidev Shouldn't it be without the curly braces and parenthesis?